# Android, how to blur/glass/frost current activity

Tags: java, android, user-interface, android-activity, background

Basically

In an activity, I have a ListView.
When I select an item, an transparent activity opens as a small box.
When this box appears, you can still view the previous activities screen,

What I am trying to figure out is how to blur the previous screen like the
image linked [here](http://xniikk.deviantart.com/art/One-V-Panels-336032755) (Ignore the UI, just look at the blurred grass area).

How is this possible?

Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

For API < 14, you could use the flag `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND`, but it's been deprecated and built-in blurring is no longer supported on higher APIs

However, you could do this with a regular view or overlay. What you want to do is:

- Create a `Bitmap` from your activity's overall layout ([see here for example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7200559/752320))
- Blur that bitmap with whatever method you want([a few examples here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2067955/752320))
- Add(or unhide) a `View` in your layout that covers everything. Set bkg to blurred Bitmap
- Open your dialog/transparent activity
- When it closes, either remove the `View`, or `setVisibility(GONE)` if you'll be using it again.

Comment: Thank you, I shall attempt this now!

Comment: Hello, The blur examples take a few seconds to blur, so this delays the opening of the new activity,
How can I get around this? As I would like it to blur and open as fast as possible.

Comment: Have you tried the NDK version of the answer shown? The author got a reported 40x speedup going native. Might be a bit much just for a blur if you're pure Java for everything else, but it's worth a shot. Another idea might be to alter the pixel loops by incrementing by 2 each round. It won't be a pixel-perfect blur, but if you just do every other pixel for both x/y, it should only take 1/4 the time. I'm not sure how it'll look, but it should only take a few minutes to change the loop to find out.

Comment: Altering the algorithm didnt work. And now finding it difficult to implement the NDK version

Comment: Unfortunately, NDK is probably your best option. A good blur isn't the hardest image processing action, but it's not the fastest, either. You might be able to find a "dirty" blur algorithm that's fast enough in Java, but I don't have one to recommend off the top of my head.

Comment: Hello, I have implemented the NDK version on the suggestion, but I cannot get the radius above 60 as it then starts to fail.
If you have any idea why, please see my post on the issue linked, if not then thank you enormously for your help. Take care.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13483556/android-ndk-gaussian-blur-implementation-cannot-exceed-radius60-and-random-act

Comment: Answer not valid answer as of now, was trying to find some alternate way for `FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND`.
Found this SO post : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10372404/alternative-to-flag-blur-behind-in-android)

Comment: @VinodJaiswal Maybe you can clarify, but I don't see what in that answer invalidates this one.

Comment: @Geobits: FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND is deprecated now and we can't achieve the blur effect by the method specified in the above answer.
I am not invalidating your answer. I am just putting my findings in here.

Comment: @VinodJaiswal I know it's deprecated; that's in the very first sentence of this answer (and has been for almost three years). The rest is a method to work around that, and will still work (even if a bit inefficient).

Comment: Is there no update to this or a better way to do this? I would imagine there are better solutions to this now.