# Google Maps with blur layer

Tags: android, google-maps

I am starting a new android app and I will use Google Maps, I am designer also and searching for inspiration I have found this screenshot: 
http://cdn1.appleinsider.com/Maps.071213.2.jpg
I really like the left screen and specially the blur layer in the botton of the image(the layer with info icon).

I´m reading something about how to blurred with android but all is using pictures, Bitmap, ImageView nothing with maps. So my questions is:
Can I make something similar (to the iOS screenshot) on android and how?
Thank you.

Comment: I think you can set the Bitmap as a background for the bottom layer. In that way you can follow examples online about blur + transparent for Bitmap http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6795483/create-blurry-transparent-background-effect and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13406060/android-how-to-blur-glass-frost-current-activity might help

Comment: Which screenshot do you want to implement ? Right side one?

Comment: Thanks @PiYusHGuPtA the left side one.

Comment: @Demetria The thing which you want to implement is a 3D google map in which you can see buildings.

Comment: @Demetria Got it now that how can you use that now??

Comment: @PiYusHGuPtA No I don´t , I will use "normal" maps (2D), I want to know if I can do, on android, the blur/glass(effect) for the buttom layer.

Comment: @PiYusHGuPtA It will be on my project a layer/layout with two icons inside, but I like that design effect

Comment: @Demetria You can use  `GoogleMap.setBuildingsEnabled(false)`. For more info http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2012/12/new-google-maps-android-api-now-part-of.html

Comment: @PiYusHGuPtA, thanks, I mean , Do you see the  info circle icon? on bottom-right, that icon is inside of one layer with blur effect, I want to make that layer.

Comment: @Demetria For that you need to make one relative layout with 50 width and put all icons in it and set blur background for that layout and also blur icons will be make designer.

Comment: @Demetria Understood? What my mean now?

Comment: yes, thanks so much @PiYusHGuPtA. but How Can I set blur background for the layout?

Comment: @Demetria For whole layout or only below icons layout??

Comment: @PiYusHGuPtA only layout

Comment: @Demetria Designer will make that background image or you can set alpha property for your layout after set background it.

Comment: @Demetria Got it now?

Comment: @PiYusHGuPtA thanks,  It is not an image as background is real time blur effect, I´m trying whit alpha property but it´s not the same.

Comment: @Demetria If you want to apply blue effect then you need to apply blur effect for bitmap of map pro grammatically.

Comment: @Demetria Now what you think how will you go?

Comment: @PiYusHGuPtA I think that is very difficult for me current android level :-(

Comment: @Demetria How much experience do you have?

Comment: @PiYusHGuPtA after ended my developer studies(3 years), 6 months working with android

Comment: @Demetria Oh. Okay. So are you currently working with android?

Comment: @Demetria Wow. Thats really great. Keep it up.

Comment: @PiYusHGuPtA Thanks for the encouragement

Comment: @Demetria Wel come. I am also working with android since 2 years.

Comment: @Demetria So now going to make blur background ?

Comment: @PiYusHGuPtA I don´t know, I´m reading that I can't not make a bitmap with google maps V2

Comment: @Demetria Means are you an able to do that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If anyone else is having problems with this, you gotta use the [Blurry library](https://github.com/wasabeef/Blurry).

But since the MapView is a surface view, it doesn't work properly with google maps, so you have to capture the `MapView`'s image into an `ImageView` and then call to Blurry, like this:

```
mGoogleMap.snapshot(new GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onSnapshotReady(Bitmap bitmap) {
                    blurView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    blurView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                    Blurry.with(getContext())
                            .radius(15)
                            .sampling(2)
                            .onto(mRootLayout);

                    mAddressBarLayout.expand();

                }
            });
```

as you can imagine, the ImageView is placed on the MapView but it's hidden at first:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

            <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
                android:id="@+id/map_fragment_mv"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/blur_view"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Helped me, Thanks! I used the method with `.from(bitmap).into(blurView);` instead to put the blurred image on the imageview so I could make it invisible later.