# Adding a blurred view over activity when opening drawer

Tags: android, android-layout

Im trying to implement a similar feature to the blurred background when opeing the drawer found in the [Sprig](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eatsprig&hl=en) app. For those unfamiliar, heres a quick screenie showing what Im talking about: http://prntscr.com/9q6t44. Basically when you open the drawer, it seems to blur and darken the background and overlay the drawer contents on top. Whats the simplest way to achieve this blur/darken effect?

I've seen a few answers that were pretty out of date, so hoping theres a new simple solution for this.

Comment: a simple search for "[android] frost" will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13406060/android-how-to-blur-glass-frost-current-activity

Comment: @petey had already found that post. Its from 2012 so is quite outdated, and recommends using the NDK for a fast blur.

Comment: Great that you are searching!!!   but http://stackoverflow.com/a/7200559/794088 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/2068981/794088  have nothing to do with the ndk.   check them out!! (dont forget to upvote should you find them helpful)

Comment: @Orbit The link that is in the post petey has contains a lot of more up-to-date variants. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067955/fast-bitmap-blur-for-android-sdk

Comment: @petey & DeeV, if you read the links you posted, most of those answers are ~5 years old, or take a few seconds to blur from a bitmap. I can generate a ViewGroups bitmap and blur it using the methods listed, but this takes 3-5 seconds. This is not what im looking for. Check out the Sprig app I linked, the effect is instant.