# Dialog: dim everything except some region

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-dialog, android-window

In my application I'm displaying an image inside a dialog. If the user presses the button the dialog appears and takes 80% of the whole screen. The background will be dimmed because that is the default behavior of the Android Dialog.

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(ActQuiz.this);
                dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
                dialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
                        //nothing;
                    }
                });

                int width = (int) (getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels * 0.80);
                int height = (int) (getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels * 0.80);
                dialog.getWindow().setLayout(width, height);
                ImageView imageView = new ImageView(ActQuiz.this);
                String uri = "@drawable/" + info.getInfopicture();
                int imageResource = getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null, getPackageName());
                Drawable myDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(ActQuiz.this, imageResource);
                imageView.setImageDrawable(myDrawable);
                new PhotoViewAttacher(imageView);
                dialog.addContentView(imageView, new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width, height));
                dialog.show();
```

So what I want to achieve is to disable the dimming for a Button, which is visible behind the dialog.

[image]

Is this possible or can I only remove the dimming for the whole background?

Comment: you can clear the Dim background behind the Dialog...is that ok ?

Comment: You probably mean: clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHI‌​ND). But it will remove the dimming for the whole background. I only want it for the button. You can see it in my post.

Comment: you can check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14030154/how-to-dim-blur-only-part-of-the-screen

Answer (score 1):

> Is this possible or can I only remove the dimming for the whole background?

It's not possible to instruct `Dialog` to dim everything except some view, or some region. There is no such an API to do that.

What you can do, is to provide your custom drawable as a background to `Dialog`'s window. That drawable would be given a `Rect` with coordinates of `Button` and a `Rect` of the screen. It will draw a dim (basically a semitransparent black color) everywhere except the provided rectangle. Looks like [xfermode SrcOut](https://techblog.badoo.com/images/masking-bitmaps/2.png) is the mode that should be applied.