# Android Dim Background of Custom Dialog

Tags: android-xml, android, android-dialog

As titled, I cannot seem to be able to dim the background of the custom dialog box I have made.  Countless solutions online mention the last 3 lines of code in the first snippet below, this has made no impact on the UI of the dialog box.

See the following code:

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
TextView textView = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textView);
textView.setText("Custom Text Example");
dialog.show();

WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
layoutParams.dimAmount = .7f;
dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(layoutParams);
```

The layout xml file for the custom dialog is as follows:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/progressDialogCustom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/dialog_black"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:text="Updating Profile . . ." />

</LinearLayout>
```

The `@drawable/dialog_black` file is as follows:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <solid android:color="@android:color/background_dark" />

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="7dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="7dp"
        android:topRightRadius="7dp" />

    <stroke
        android:width="1px"
        android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <padding
        android:bottom="5dp"
        android:left="5dp"
        android:right="5dp"
        android:top="5dp" />

</shape>
```

Comment: would this be of any help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10372404/alternative-to-flag-blur-behind-in-android  ?

Comment: Thanks, the relevant information on setting the dim level is already included within my code though, (for reference, those last 3 lines in the first snippet).

Comment: but did you use : dialog.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND);  
 ?

Comment: That method is deprecated.  It also did not solve the problem upon implementation.

Comment: weird, as I recall, it worked even on newer android versions. maybe now it won't work anymore.

Answer (score 13):

Have you tried adding:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
```

`dimAmount` is ignored unless this flag is present.

Comment: Yes.  I currently just have a workaround in which I set the dialog to take the full screen and set its parent view to just consist of a semi-transparent 1px * 1px 9 patch drawable

Comment: Yes this line of code is working. I have added the dimAmount but its not working without this line.