# Dim background of DialogFragment on Android 4.4.4 (KitKat)

Tags: android, android-support-library

I have a DialogFragment (from `android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment`) where the activity behind dims perfectly as expected on my Android 5.1 (Lollipop). But on Kitkat, the dimming does not work.

I tried the following solutions but failed:

1. [Android Dim Background of Custom Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21613238/android-dim-background-of-custom-dialog)
2. [DialogFragment with clear background (not dimmed)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13822842/dialogfragment-with-clear-background-not-dimmed)

Am I missing something? TIA.

**EDIT 1:**

This is my `onCreateDialog` method of the `DialogFragment`.

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dialog, null);
    ...
    // set textfield listeners here
    ...
    builder.setView(layout);
    return builder.create();
}
```

Here is my `DialogFragment` layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">
    ...
</LinearLayout>
```

As you can see, I am not doing anything special in my layout xml.

And this is how I call the dialog up:

```
MyDialogFragment dialog = new MyDialogFragment();
dialog.setListener(this);
dialog.setCallingActivity(this);
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
dialog.show(fm, "MyDialogFragment");
```

Comment: Can you show us your XML layouts and at least the `onCreateView` and/or `onCreateDialog` methods in your DialogFragment, as well as how the dialog is invoked from the activity?

Comment: Updated. I am not doing anything special in any of my source codes. This works perfectly fine on my Lollipop device.

Comment: That looks perfectly normal.  Using the same code (minus your custom `setListener()` `setCallingActivty()` calls) does show a dimmed background on my tablet running KitKat 4.4.2.  May be something specific to 4.4.4 or your device-specific Android build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to fix the dim issue on Android 4.4.4. The best result that I got was from this dialog:

[image]

into this nicer dialog with elevation

[image]

To do this, simply use this import of the `DialogFragment`:

```
import android.app.DialogFragment;
```

Finally, of course, use the proper `FragmentManager`:

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
```

Cheers!