# Why “FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND” is deprecated in Android?

Tags: android, dialog, deprecated

I was wondering why it is deprecated. After searching i found a related question asked here -

[Alternative to "FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND" in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10372404/alternative-to-flag-blur-behind-in-android)

which tells about the alternatives. But why Android deprecated FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND?

Comment: It was deprecated in Android Level 15, back in 2012 (8 years ago!)

Comment: yeah but what was the reason to deprecate this? This was a handy flag.